# Android project firebase crashlytics does not show crash free users about specific version

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

In my android last version I have removed firebase analytics library from my project and ı have released it. After that I could not see crash free users with my last version on crashlytics but I can see older versions rates. Is it necessary to use analytics library to see crash free user? Is there another way to see that?.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, the crash free users data comes from the Analytics SDK. If it was removed or it isn't working properly in this version of the app, it could explain this.